# Twitter streaming API in Java with tracks that have spaces?

Tags: java, twitter

Two Java libraries to connect to the Twitter streaming API are [twitter4j](http://twitter4j.org) and [tweetstream4j](http://github.com/seejohnrun/tweetStream4J).

The Twitter streaming API allows ["tracks" with spaces](http://dev.twitter.com/pages/streaming_api_methods#track):

> Comma separated keywords and phrases are logical ORs, phrases are logical ANDs. Words within phrases are delimited by spaces. A tweet matches if any phrase matches. A phrase matches if all of the words are present in the tweet. (e.g. ‘the twitter’ is the AND twitter, and ‘the,twitter’ is the OR twitter.).

However, trying to use tracks with spaces in twitter4j causes [an error](http://twitter4j.org/jira/browse/TFJ-420) (401 unauthorized).  tweetstream4j also throws a 401 when using tracks with spaces.

Has anyone used a Java library to connect to the Twitter streaming API and used tracks with spaces? Which library and version?

Answer (score 0):

Yusuke [claims to have fixed this](http://twitter4j.org/jira/browse/TFJ-420) for twitter4j 2.1.7.